# adding css class dynamically results in undesired immediately after

Tags: javascript, css

I'm adding a css class dynamically with javascript to parent div. Then, I try to add a child div inside that parent div that is styled as `position: absolute`.

Since child div is `position: absolute` I would have expected it to show up above the content. 
How can I get it to show above the content?

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/w2ucD/1/)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/w2ucD/2/)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .parentdiv
        {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 150px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .childdiv
        {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid green;
            height: 10px;
            width: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div id="div1" class="test">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var strContent = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
                document.writeln(i + '<br />');
            }
        </script>

    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            var d1 = document.getElementById('div1');
            var strContent = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                strContent += (i + '<br />');
            }
            d1.innerHTML = strContent;

            d1.className += (' ' + 'parentdiv');

            var d2 = document.createElement('div');
            d2.className = 'childdiv';
            d1.appendChild(d2);
        };
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you not have to give the parent a position setting also?

Comment: child should be top 0px

Comment: Above meaning exactly where ? You should add top and left values to your child element to place it exactly where you want it to be. Absolute elements with no top/left values are just positioned  with the flow of the document, in this case, just after your parent div ( or after all the -br- in the second example ).

Comment: by above if you mean on top of the parent layer (parent div in background, child div in foreground) then you have to use `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want the child to be within the parent and hide its content.

When you set position:absolute to an item it will refer to the window or to the closest parent having "position:relative" or "position:absolute".

In addition, you need to set coords to the child.

So:

- Set position:relative to the parent
- Set top:0px; left:0px; to the child
- Recommended: create another sibling to the child and put there all the numbers. It's not a good practice to put text and BR as siblings to DIVs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w2ucD/4/ This is what I'm expecting but generally the content comes first.

Comment: What do you mean by first? On the z axis on on the y axis? I mean, you want the childdiv to appear after the numbers (on the y axis)? or be hidden under them (on the z axis)?